# log parser error

Tags: com, parsing, logging

I have never used log parser before..
well I am getting this error now.. i don't know the reason..

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8CFEBA94-3FC2-45CA-B9A5-9EDACF704F66} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

can ya help me out with this..
:)

Answer (score 3):

The error code means the class in not registered. Running the following command will probably solve the problem:

```
regsvr32 <path>\LogParser.dll
```

If you move the DLL around (install it with your app, for instance), you'll have to repeat the call each time. Or, if you'd like to install it from your app, you can call the exported DLLRegisterServer, which is what regsvr32 calls.

Comment: thank you...
well i was missing more than a dll..
i just installed my logparser again..
but thanks for ur reply.. :)

Comment: It's true that the DLL is not registered, but the solution is rather to install Log Parser as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22401765/4100001.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer:

Download and install [Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659)